# Performance issue updating 9 million records using a script

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

We have been running the below script to update a few columns in table running 11G oracle DB (11.2.0.3) and it is taking about 61 hours to complete which is surprising as we are using Bulk collect and Forall to do the actual update. We have also enabled parallel dml. We are also trying to update based on rowid rather than using a column which is indexed as we think that would be faster. Any advices to speed this up would be great. Below is the script

```
ALTER session enable parallel dml;
DECLARE
i NUMBER;
j number :=0 ;
TYPE tab_type IS TABLE OF rowid index by binary_integer;
tab_id tab_type;

CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT /*+ parallel(na,DEFAULT) */
                   rowid
                             from sample_table na
                             FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO tab_id LIMIT 10000;
    EXIT WHEN tab_id.COUNT = 0;

    FORALL i IN 1..tab_id.COUNT
                             update sample_table 
        set col1 = 'XXX'
        , col2 = 'XXX'
        , col3 = 'XXX'
        , col4 = 'XXX'
                             , col5= 'XXX'
        , col6 = 'XXX' 
     WHERE rowid = tab_id(i);
              j := j+1;
              if mod(j, 1000) = 0 THEN    -- Commit every 1000 records
                    COMMIT;
              end if;


  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c1;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure this will have effect on your run time, but i cannot hurt it. Further your code indicate a couple misconceptions.

1. First the [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) statement does not create a loop. It runs the
   single incorporated 1 time, processing the the entire collection.
2. This also means your commit interval is NOT 1000 as you indicate but
   1M.
3. The index variable (i) in the the statement is local to that
   statement and can only be accessed within the scope of the forall
   statement. So the declared variable i is not the variable used in
   the forall and therefore is not needed. There is no error because of
   scoping rules.
4. Since there is no commit after exiting your loop the last set will
   not be committed unless the number of rows is an exact multiple of
   the commit interval. In your case with a 1M row commit interval if you 8,999,999 rows then only 8M would be committed.

With all this in mind, you can try:

```
declare
  type tab_type is table of rowid;
  tab_id tab_type;

  k_buffer_limit constant pls_integer  := 10000;

 cursor c1 is
        select /*+ parallel(na,DEFAULT) */
               rowid
          from sample_table na
           for update skip locked;
begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 bulk collect into tab_id limit 10000

    forall i in 1..tab_id.count
      update sample_table 
         set col1 = 'XXX'
           , col2 = 'XXX'
           , col3 = 'XXX'
           , col4 = 'XXX'
           , col5=  'XXX'
           , col6 = 'XXX' 
      where rowid = tab_id(i);

     commit;    
     exit when tab_id.count < k_buffer_limit; 
  end loop;

  close c1;

end;
```

5. Bulk collect/ Forall processing is trade off between context switch
   and memory usage. While reducing context switching is a good thing, that
   may be overcome by the memory requirements. Your process may be
   going into a wait to get sufficient memory. You may get better performance by [lowering the buffer size](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-bulk-collect).

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I think the commit would have to be moved after closing the cursor as it may cause a fetch out of sequence error.

Comment: A commit does NOT do another fetch. It could go either before or after close cursor and would have no effect either way.  The commit has no knowledge of nor effect on  the cursor since they solved to cursor instability issue across commits (around  v9? or v10? somewhere in there).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.